# SQL Server Management Studio deleted my database during copy

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, copy, delete-file

I was copying a database using the SQL Server Management Studio Wizard and made the mistake of deleting the SQL Server Job created to copy it whilst the job was running.

My source database has now disappeared. I did a search on my computer and used a win mapping tool to see if I could see it but no luck.

Does anybody have any ideas how I can find my database again? It surely isn't lost!

Comment: I would try to do the same procedure again (on a different database and preferably on a different computer) so that I could investigate the script that would have been generated - to see where any interim files would have been created.  This may give you a clue where to go looking on your computer.  Best of luck...  <mutters something under his breath about backups...>

Comment: Just restore it from your most recent backup ....

Comment: Did you use the detach-method for the database copy? If so, the database files will/should still be present on the drive. The detach simply puts the database in a consistent state, and then removes the database from SQL Server to ensure the files aren't locked. However, the physical files will be there, and you should be able to easily attach the database again.

Comment: Unless you changed the filepaths for the database (if it's a production database, I hope you did), try checking the default filepath:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA`

Comment: Thanks guys - cant see the files. I didnt back up as this is a Proof of Concept that took a bit longer to dev than i thought and so with hindsight i should have had a backup :(

Answer (score 1):

Search all drives for `*.mdf` files and review all of them. Likely, they are still there. You can attach database files to make them known to SQL Server again.

Windows Search might not have them indexed, so use *Everything Search* to be safe.

Comment: whats everything search?

Comment: http://www.voidtools.com/download.htm It's a simple search tool that indexes everything and hides nothing.